# Creating a byte array of a certain size

Tags: java

I need to create a byte array with 100 bytes from a string. The length of the string is unknown but it is always less than 100 bytes. So if the string is 65 bytes then i need the array to be 35 zero bytes and then the String bytes to follow.

At the moment i have something like this, that does the job, but maybe something prettier and optimized is possible :)

```
    String string = "asdf";
    byte[] stringBytes = string.getBytes();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(new byte[100 - stringBytes.length]);
    outputStream.write(stringBytes);    
    byte[] result = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: There's no need for the OutputStream. Just do new byte[100] and use System.arraycopy to transfer the bytes into it.

Comment: Yes, I would imagine something prettier and optimized is possible

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
String string = "asdf";
byte[] result = new byte[100];
System.arraycopy(string.getBytes(), 0, result, 100 - string.length(), string.length());
```